# Framework para documentação para API REST java

Tags: java, api, restful, documentação

Olá,

Tenho um projecto em java, com APIs em REST. Queria criar uma wiki com documentação (markdown+swagger) sobre as APIs localmente, incluindo também uma forma de testar a API(API console/explorer).
São APIs com autenticação do tipo IDP (OAUTH), com tokens.

Alguma sugestão de framework que me preste este tipo de serviço?

Obrigado.

Comment: O próprio swagger não te atende?

Comment: O problema do swagger é que, pelo que vi, não aceita markdowns, não, Não consigo detalhar muito a API, especie de uma wiki, ou consigo?